# RS485: ioctl: ttyS1 not a tty device

Tags: drivers, tty

I have a board with UART, and an external converter to RS485. It sits at /dev/ttyS1. The converter requires that I put the UART RTS pin to high when sending and to low when receiving. I can achieve that by manipulating the pin from user-space before read/write calls, but I'd much prefer to have the serial driver do that. I follow verbatim the example in [Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt), but what I get from `ioctl()` is `ENOTTY` - not a tty device. How can I proceed to understand the issue?

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Aug 29 09:16 /dev/ttyS1
```

Comment: According to the `ioctl(2)` man page, `ENOTTY` means "the specified request does not apply to the kind of object referenced to by the file descriptor in the call". You said you have an *external* RS485 converter, so the kernel is not aware that the UART is actually driving a RS485 port, and that UART may or may not be capable of the RS485 mode by itself. The document you linked applies only to UARTs with a *built-in* RS485 mode.

Comment: @telcoM Yeah, that makes sense.