# Hardware controlled RTS on tty

Tags: drivers, serial-port, uart

I have a UART whose RTS pin is connected to an external RS485 transceiver, so that asserting the RTS pin would set the transceiver to send mode. I thought I could configure the serial port to use the RTS signal, thus eliminating the need to manually toggle the pin from user space. When configuring the port (ttyS1) I use `struct termios options` with `options.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS`. But this has no effect on the relevant pin. I'm on kernel 4.14 (but can move to 4.16/17).

Any ideas?

Comment: Reading the kernel [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt) on the subject may help.

Comment: @meuh, my rs485 transceiver is external, so the kernel doesn't know about it. I indeed tried using the approach in that doc: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465491/rs485-ioctl-ttys1-not-a-tty-device

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the device tree did not correctly configure the RTS and CTS pins for use with the relevant UART. The device tree should contain something like:

```
&uart1 {
  pinctrl-names = "default";
  pinctrl-0 = <&uart1_pins>, <&uart1_rts_cts_pins>;
  status = "okay";
};
```

Where the pins have been appropriately defined earlier.